# Why different transformation behaviour ArcGIS Pro 2D/3D layers?

Tags: 3d, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro

I am working with ArcGIS Pro and have noticed a strange difference between the co-ordinate transformation of 2D and 3D layers.

Here are my transformation settings:

[image]

I have the same layer represented in 2D and 3D but you can see they do not align:

[image: 3D layer: apparently no transformation]

3D layer: apparently no transformation

[image: 2D layer: correct transformation]

2D layer: correct transformation

Has anyone else experienced this issue before?